# How AFNetworking nsrunloop stop

Tags: afnetworking, nsrunloop

I want to learn some knowledge of the nsrunloop by learning the afnetworking source code. The af devs add the machport to the separated thread's runloop to keep the thread alive, but how does the af thread stop. I know that af operation sets the finish state (via the kvo way) indicating that the operation finished when the url connection has error or finishes loading, however, there is no place that it removes the mach port from the runloop, so how can the runloop stop?

it assigns nil to the connection, and closes the outputstream, but it doesn't remove the machport, so I guess the runloop is still running.